# Find 'Application Files' directory after publish by ClickOnce

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, clickonce, publish

After publish by using ClickOnce in C#, I got fully confused about **how to find the directory of the folder: 'Application Files'**. The reason I want to do this is I want to put some files into this folder and let C# to read them after the user installed my application.

I have tried like: `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)`,
but I always got like: `C:\Users\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\4DAZ7HKJ.7TP\OZ02N2HD.7PG\cons..tion_a9321ce7eb14b63e_0001.0000_7ed45506b35ff771`, which I don't want. Since my publish folder is in `D:\`, what I want is like: `D:\Application Files`.

Thanks in advance to anyone who read my question!

[image: publish folder after clickOnce publish]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To include a file to your publish, you don't need to include it in the folder manually, instead you should add the file to your project and set its `Build Action` to `Content`. To make sure the file is included in publish, go to `Project → Properties → Publish Tab → Application Files Button` and see if `Publish Status` of your file is `Include (Auto)`.

After deploying the application those files will be deployed near the application executable file. For example if you include `image.png`, then you can find it this way:

```
var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "image.png");
```

Also if for any reason you are looking for your publish folder you can see the path you used for publish, in `Project → Properties → Publish → Publish Location` or in `<PublishUrl>` tag in your project file.

Regardless of the location you published the files, there is a copy of them in the `\bin\debug` folder of your project under `app.publish` folder.

Comment: Thank you for the edit.
I know I can include some extra files into the publish. But I don't want to find them manually. How to find them by coding is what I want. 
Like, 'Console.WriteLine(the path of the extra files);'
Do you have any idea?

Comment: The files will be deployed near the application exe file. For example if you include `image.png`, then you can find it this way: `var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "image.png");`

Comment: I tried System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "image.png"); but it shows an error that: 'The name 'Application' does not exist in the current context.' What should I do?

Comment: The full name is `System.Windows.Forms.Application`. You can call it `Application` when you have a `using System.Windows.Forms;`

Comment: Although what I want to build is an Excel AddIn, but it still works! I got 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\Root\Office15\ExtraFile.txt'. As you can see, this is not 'D:\', but it seems that I don't need to care where the extra files are, since I can find where are they now. I will keep experimenting this.
Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. While I have no idea about using click once for deploying an excel add-in, but in general, at least for deploying  applications you don't need to worry about those files. The path of deployment is not important. The important thing is those files are there and accessible by your code.

Comment: I am sorry to tell you that after tests, I found that the content files of the project are not in the location, like: 'System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "extra_file.txt")', I got an error from this when I want to read the context from the extra_file.txt.
I do wish I could accept your answer, so, do you have any other idea? 
Besides, what I am working on is an excel addin.

Comment: Since the question is about an application (like console application which is obvious in the image in question), I believe the post answers the question and if you have another question about deploying an excel add-in using click once, it's better to ask a new question about *deploying excel add-in using click once* and ask about how to find those files. I'll try to answer your new question if I had anything to share :)

Comment: got this. Thanks! I will post a new question.

Comment: absolutely! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Following this path you do not want, you find an executable capable of respecting what you expect to have using
`System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)`

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for the WPF way, here two equivalent methods:

`var appPath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

`var appPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName)`

and then use it like this:

`var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(appPath, "image.png");`